# How to host my site in gitlab as my myname.gitlab.io

Tags: gitlab

Suppose my gitlab username is `test`. I want to host my site as `https://test.gitlab.io` without `baseurl`. Is it possible. I mean instead of `https://test.gitlab.io/username`, I need `https://test.gitlab.io`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [GitLab pages documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_one.html#user-and-group-website-examples), it would seem you can do it like this:

> Under your username, `john`, you created a project called `john.gitlab.io`. Your project URL will be `https://gitlab.com/john/john.gitlab.io`. Once you enable GitLab Pages for your project, your website will be published under `https://john.gitlab.io`.